# How do I prove that hyperbolic triangles are convex?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, convex-geometry

I was introduced to both the Poincaré disc model and the upper half-plane model and need to prove the statement in the title. Apparently you can do this by showing that sectors in the disc model with central angle < $\pi$ and vertical strips in the upper half-plane model are convex. Using that, you show that a triangle in the upper half-plane is the intersection of three "suitable" convex sets and is therefore also convex.

I understand why vertical strips are convex, but other than that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hint: Show that the intersection of convex sets is convex, then show that the half-plane is convex. The triangle is the intersection of three half-planes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure what you mean. I know that the intersection of convex sets is convex and obviously the entire half plane is convex too. How is a triangle the intersection of three half-planes? Isn't there only one half-plane, i.e. the space we're operating in?

Comment: No, the half of the hyperbolic plane - one side of a hyperbolic line in the model. Triangles in the models are not convex in terms of the Euclidean sense - a Euclidean line segment between two  points in a hyperbolic triangle is not necessarily contained entirely in the hyperbolic triangle. So I assumed you meant the convex in the hyperbolic plane. Then, it is not 100% obvious that the set of points on one side of a hyperbolic line (a hyperbolic half-plane) is convex hyperbolically complex.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ahh, now I understand. In my textbook the word half-plane is just used to describe the hyperbolic plane (since it's "half" of the complex plane) and never like that. I was asking about "hyperbolic convexity", just like you thought.

I'm not sure how to show that the set of points on one side of a hyperbolic line is convex though (unless the hyperbolic line is a parallel to the imaginary axis). I tried to use the construction for the hyperbolic line between to points and somehow argue with that, but I can't quite figure it out

Comment: Following the ideas provided above, you can try to show that hyperbolic convexity is preserved by $PSL_2\mathbb{R}$